# Run Libreoffice Macro on Docker container

Tags: excel, vba, docker, libreoffice

I have an Excel macro which I want to run inside a docker container using libreoffice command line. I am using the following command:

```
libreoffice ./Macro-enabled_workbook1.xlsm "vnd.sun.star.script:VBAProject.ThisWorkbook.NameSheetsFromAList?language=Basic&location=document" --headless
```

When I run this command, the command seems to be stuck.

From what I have understood so far, I think it's because of Macro Security settings of Libreoffice. In a GUI environment, libreoffice asks the user to set the Macro Security level before running macros. But, since I want to run it on a docker container, I am not able to change the Macro Security Level. Is there any way I can change the Macro Security Level or add a Trusted Path to Libreoffice using command line?

Comment: If you could bypass a user's security like that, it wouldn't be very secure.

Comment: In addition to the security issue, most VBA code cannot be executed by LibreOffice. It must be rewritten in Basic instead, using the UNO API.